# Kivy GridLayout scaling issues - Android vs PC - 16:9 and 19:5:9 vs 4:3(1920x1080 and 1440x3120 vs 800x600)

Tags: python, android, kivy, scaling, buildozer

I've been making an Android Snake game using `kivy` and `buildozer` and after many iterations of using different values, layouts and approaches(and many searches on Google, StackOverflow and `kivy` forums/documentation) I've reached a point where I am seeking help here myself.

The issue is so;
the grid looks great when the kivy window is 800x600, with the goal of the rectangles being perfect, even sided squares. The moment the window maximizes and the window turns into 1920x1080(16:9), the squares become wide rectangles and thus uneven. Unfortunately, trying the game on my OnePlus 7 Pro, with the aspect ratio of 19:5:9 and resolution of 1440x3120 the undesired result is even more extreme.

currently I am using a `GridLayout` populated by `Rectangle` to achieve the level's grid. I've tried making formulas based on `Window.size`, `Window.width`, I've tried using `size_hint`, `size`, `width`, `cols_minimum` and `kivy.metrics` so far with no success.

As a side note, if anything of what I am trying to achieve or in the code below can be done in a better way, please let me know. Any alternatives would be appreciated, I am very inexperienced and new to both `kivy` and `Python`.

My code:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class GridCell(Widget):
    color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    size = ListProperty([0, 0])
    pos = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def __init__(self, size, x, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        self.size = (size, size)
        self.pos = (x, y)


class Level(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 30
        self.cell_size = 28
        self.spacing = 2
        self.positions = [(row, column) for row in range(self.cols) for column
                          in range(self.cols)]
        self.grid_cells = {}
        self.create_grid()

    def create_grid(self):
        for position in self.positions:
            self.grid_cells[position] = GridCell(self.cell_size, *position)
            self.add_widget(self.grid_cells[position])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App
    Builder.load_file('grid_cell.kv')
    Window.clearcolor = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)


    class LevelApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.title = 'Level'
            level = Level()
            return level


    level_app = LevelApp()
    level_app.run()
```

grid_cell.kv:

```
<GridCell>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Comment: Does adding `self.size_hint = (None, None)` to your `__init__()` method of `GridCell` help? Without that, your size settings are ignored.

Comment: It corrects the size but the grid no longer fills the window. If possible I'd rather keep the auto scaling working and just make sure both columns and rows are the same size..

Comment: It seems to change the number of rows/column for some reason as well? Or at least they go out of the window.

Comment: For context as well at least with my current snake/fruit implementation of movement, spawning and respawning those changes break the all of them as well. Really trying to find changes that would avoid hardcoding as much as possible and work on as many as possible resolutions and aspect ratios.. At least on Android.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify or add to help towards solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you cannot fill a non-square window with a square grid of square cells. But, to keep the cells square and base their size on the `GridLayout`, try changing the `GridCell` class to:

```
class GridCell(Widget):
    color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    def __init__(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        self.pos = (x, y)
```

Note that you don't need to define `pos` and `size` properties since `Widget` already has them, and I have removed `size` from the `__init__()` method.

And change `Level` to:

```
class Level(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 30
        self.rows = 30
        self.spacing = 2
        self.positions = [(row, column) for row in range(self.rows) for column
                          in range(self.cols)]
        self.grid_cells = {}
        self.create_grid()

    def create_grid(self):
        for position in self.positions:
            self.grid_cells[position] = GridCell(*position)
            self.add_widget(self.grid_cells[position])
```

Then in your `kv`:

```
<GridCell>:
    grid_cols: self.parent.cols if self.parent and self.parent.cols else 1
    grid_rows: self.parent.rows if self.parent and self.parent.rows else 1
    tmp_size: min(self.parent.width/self.grid_cols - self.parent.spacing[0], self.parent.height/self.grid_rows - self.parent.spacing[1]) if self.parent else 0
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.tmp_size, self.tmp_size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

This calculates a `tmp_size` based on the `GridLayout` `size`, `rows`, and `cols`, and assigns that size to the `GridCell`. The `if` statements in the `kv` are necessary because the `<GridCell>` rule is applied before the `GridCell` gets its `parent` assigned.

Comment: Would changing the number of rows/columns based on resolution/aspect ratio be safe, viable, scalable and flexible enough?

Comment: In general, changing the rows/columns in a dynamic way?

Comment: I have updated my answer so that the `GridCell` size is now calculated based on the `Level` `size`, `rows`, and `cols`.

Comment: So just to be clear.. Is there no way around how half~ of the window is empty?

Comment: I will look into a shape somewhere between a rectangle and a square with a reasonable size, amount of rows and columns and then fill the empty space with information and functionalities. Thank you so much for your time and help. @John Anderson